# SetupDiGetClassDevs - Get name shown in USB devices from deviceinstanceid?

Tags: winapi

I have a printer connected that doesn't have a driver and doesn't show up under printers, but it shows up under "Start->Settings->Bluetooth & other devices" with name "SRP300".

I can send data to the printer via the following routine (found here : https://www.levelextreme.com/ViewPageGenericLogin.aspx?LoadContainer=1&NoThread=1157607 ) where it gets the Device Instance ID, and Guid - but I'm simply not able to figure out where I am to get the name from "SP300".

What would I need to call as soon as I've found the GUID of it? The best would be if I could search for the name to start with and if SP300 is found then get the instance id/guid, but I've tried different approaches enumerating to get that name that is shown but nothing seem to produce it.

If I inspect the registry I can see that it's grouped under USB and then under a folder called USBPRINT and then a folder 00000001 and in there there is the name, but wonder how I'm able to retrieve this with Win api calls?

```
int test2()
{
int           MemberIndex = 0;
LONG          Result = 0;
DWORD         Length = 0;
HANDLE        hDevInfo;
ULONG         Required;

HANDLE m_hComm=NULL;

PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA detailData = NULL;

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA  devInfoData;

hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs((LPGUID)&(USB_PRINT), NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE);

if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{

    printf("No hardware device");
    return 0;
}

devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

//Step through the available devices looking for the one we want. 
do
{
    //[1]
    Result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, 0, (LPGUID)&(USB_PRINT), MemberIndex, &devInfoData);
    if (Result != 0)
    {
        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, NULL, 0, &Length, NULL);
        //Allocate memory for the hDevInfo structure, using the returned Length.

        detailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)new BYTE[Length * 4];
        //Set cbSize in the detailData structure.

        detailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
        //Call the function again, this time passing it the returned buffer size.

        if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, detailData, Length, &Required, NULL) == TRUE)
        {
            m_hComm = CreateFile(detailData->DevicePath,
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
            if (m_hComm != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                //Result = 0;
                printf("USB port Available");
            }
            CloseHandle(m_hComm);
        }
        delete(detailData);
    }
    MemberIndex = MemberIndex + 1;

} while (Result != 0);

SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);

printf("%u\r\n", MemberIndex);
;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If an enumeration parameter value is not used to select devices, set Enumerator to NULL and when Enumerator is NULL, SetupDiGetClassDevs returns devices for all PnP enumerators. You could set this parameter either be the value's globally unique identifier (GUID) or symbolic name.

For more information, you could refer to this document below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw

Best Regards,

Baron Bi

Comment: Im able to get the device and guid but i dont know which function get the name displayed in the other devices it doesnt seem to be in devices. Was thinking if it was possible to call one function ex with the guid and that would return the "human names" ?